# How do I test the javascript object without mocking?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I have a file 'handler.js';

```
module.exports = {
  name: 'Apple'
}
```

I want to test this object to restrict the name property value to change.

Tests handler.test.js

when I imported the module and get the name property, value is coming up as undefined

```
import handler from './handler.js';
it('verify the name property value', () => {
    expect(handler.name).toBe('Apple');
  });
```

I also tried mocking the object, it works but if I change the name value to something like 'orange' in the actual handler file, the test still works. So I want to restrict the object to change.

```
jest.doMock('./handler', () => {
    return {
      __esModule: true,
      name: 'Apple',
    };
  });
  return import('./handler').then((moduleName) => {
    expect(moduleName.name).toEqual('Apple');
  });
```

Comment: The semicolon in `handler.js` in the middle of the object literal is not valid syntax. Remove it or replace it with a comma. This may prevent that module from being loaded, which may be why you're getting `undefined`. If you fix that, does that help?

Comment: @AlexWayne That's a typo. Fixed it.